# Right way to define MongoDB in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm using MongoDB in my project but apparently Doctrine update their bundle and now I'm having issues if I run "composer update" command. This is my doctrine.yml file:

```
# ODM
doctrine_odm.mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: mongodb://%mongo_host%:%mongo_port%
      options: {}
  default_database: %mongo_database%
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
```

But I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "doctrine_odm.mongodb" (in
>   /var/www/html/kraken/app/config/doctrine.yml).

If I use this other configuration:

```
# ODM
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: mongodb://%mongo_host%:%mongo_port%
      options: {}
  default_database: %mongo_database%
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
```

Then the error transform to this one:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>   The service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_configuration" has a
>   dependency on a non-existent parameter
>   "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_commit_options". Did you mean one of
>   these: "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection",
>   "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager"?

What I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add (I have had the same problem few minutes ago when I ran composer update):

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    default_commit_options: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer. This seems to be a known issue.

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/222

The solution is to add a default option:

doctrine_mongodb:

```
default_commit_options: ~
```