# Using mongodb in symfony4.1

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony4

My problem is very simple. I cannot use **doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle** in my symfony4 project.

I followed this : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

I did also this : [Right way to define MongoDB in config.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555560/right-way-to-define-mongodb-in-config-yml)

I have a file *doctrine_mongodb.yml* under config/packages :

```html
parameters:
  mongodb_server: "mongodb://localhost:27017"
  mongodb_database_name: test

doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: "%mongodb_server%"
      options: {}
  default_database: "%mongodb_database_name%"
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
  default_commit_options: ~
```

In my **composer.json** I have this :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.5",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
    "symfony/asset": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/requirements-checker": "^1.1",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/templating": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/translation": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.1.*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.1.*"
},
```

When I do **composer update**, I have this error:

```html
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.1.*"
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In FileLoader.php line 168:
!!                                                                                 
!!    There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_mongodb"  
!!     (in /home/user/Projects/project/config/packages/doctrine_mongodb.yml).   
!!    Looked for namespace "doctrine_mongodb", found "framework", "doctrine_cache  
!!    ", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security",  
!!     "swiftmailer", "web_profiler", "twig", "monolog", "debug", "maker", "web_s  
!!    erver" in /home/user/Projects/project/config/packages/doctrine_mongodb.y  
!!    ml (which is loaded in resource "/home/user/Projects/project/config/pack  
!!    ages/doctrine_mongodb.yml").                                                 
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  In YamlFileLoader.php line 657:
!!                                                                                 
!!    There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_mongodb"  
!!     (in /home/user/Projects/project/config/packages/doctrine_mongodb.yml).   
!!    Looked for namespace "doctrine_mongodb", found "framework", "doctrine_cache  
!!    ", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security",  
!!     "swiftmailer", "web_profiler", "twig", "monolog", "debug", "maker", "web_s  
!!    erver"                                                                       
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

It would be awesome if I can resolve this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found !

Missing bundle in bundles.php ;)

```
Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```